# Lorentz transformation in spherical coordinates?

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am doing a practice problem (question 2006 in [Lim](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KD4LyQx_1JAC&source=gbs_navlinks_s),1995<sup>1</sup>) which involves finding the flux of a star in an arbitrary inertial frame. given that it emits at luminosity $L$ at a frame at rest with respect to the star.

The author starts, in an earlier part of the question, by finding the stress-energy (/energy-momentum) tensor in spherical coordinates getting:
$$ \newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} \newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\e}[0]{\varepsilon} T^{ij}=\f{L}{4\pi r^2 c}\begin{pmatrix}1 &1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
He then goes onto complete the question making no apparent use of this. My first thought however, would be to perform a Lorentz transform on this tensor to get the flux in a new frame. However, I have no idea how to do a Lorentz transform in spherical coordinates and can't seem to find any methodology in books or on the Internet. Can it be done? and if so how?

<sup>1</sup><sub>If you type '2006' into the book search on the linked page you may be able to see the question in full.</sub>

Comment: What about the standard $T'_{\mu\nu}=\frac{\partial x'_\mu}{\partial x_\tau}\frac{\partial x'_\nu}{\partial x_\rho}T_{\tau\rho}$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform The problem is that I don't know how to write $x_\mu'$ in terms of $x_\tau$.

Comment: then how do you even define your new frame?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I guess as an inertial frame moving with velocity $\vec v$ w.r.t. the star with spherical coordinates centered on the star?!

Comment: So you have: 1) a relation between Cartesian and spherical coordinates; 2) a relation between two Cartesian systems (Lorentz transformations); 3) another relation between Cartesian and spherical in the moving reference frame. Combining the three to get the transformation law in spherical coordinates seems like a purely computational exercise.